# JAVA Comparing two Strings isn't working

Tags: java

So here's a snippet of code I'm working on:

```
String direction = s.readLine();
System.out.println(direction);
if (direction.equals("up") != true && direction.equals("down") != true &&
  direction.equals("left") != true && direction.equals("right") &&
  direction.equals(null) != true) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Solution file");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

What it is supposed to do is read a line from a text file (using a `BufferedReader`) and then if the line isn't either a valid direction or blank then it should print "Invalid Solution" and exit.

The problem is that no matter what the direction string is the if statement still runs. I put in a println to check whether the direction was being read correctly but it seems absolutely fine. So why isn't the code working as intended?

Comment: Also, `!= true` looks weird. Use the `!`  ("Not") operator on each term, instead.

Comment: `direction.equals(null) != true` are you trying to compare with empty string? that should be `direction.equals("") != true`

Comment: @mmm That isn't correct based on his problem, he does indeed want `&&` because he is trying to find string entries that match none of the valid directions

Comment: Yes, @JamesWierzba you're right... Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Part of your problem is readability. Fix that and your problem is 90% solved:

```
private static List<String> DIRECTIONS = Arrays.asList("up", "down", "left", "right");
```

then

```
if (!DIRECTIONS.contains(direction)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Solution file");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

The other 10% was how to check for null, which is `direction == null`, but if you use this code you don't need to, because `contains(null)` will conveniently return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Here  `&& direction.equals("right")` I think you have done a mistake since it is on contradiction with the rest :

```
direction.equals("up") != true && 
direction.equals("down") != true && 
direction.equals("left") != true
```

You test the negation in the most of conditions but `direction.equals("right")` tests the affirmation.

Try it , it's the same thing but less verbose and more readable :

```
if (direction !=null && !direction.equals("up") && 
                        !direction.equals("down") &&  
                        !direction.equals("left") && 
                        !direction.equals("right") ){
           System.out.println("Invalid Solution file");
           System.exit(0);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You code is much more complex than it is needs to.

Consider this instead:

```
Set<String> validDirections = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("up", "down", ...
if (validDirections.contain(direction.toLowerCase()) {
  // good ...
} else {
  // bad ..
}
```

You can make `validDirections` a global constant for example; so it could be used in other places as well.

What I am trying to explain here is: your code is **low-level**. Low level code is hard to write, read, maintain and extend. Programming is always about creating good **abstractions**. Or vice versa: if you don't use abstractions, you end up with pretty abstract code, like the one you are showing here!

For example: if you need another direction, you have to put into your already way too complicated if condition. In my solution, you just put it into the statement that builds that Set.

Finally: your error message, is saying nothing. So, that string is bad; but why is it? Wouldn't it be better to at least print the string that caused the error?!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use `!= true` with a boolean statement, it is bad form. Rewrite like this:

`direction !=null &&
!direction.equals("up") &&
!direction.equals("down") &&
!direction.equals("left") &&
!direction.equals("right")`

Your error was that you did not include the `!= true` part on one of your statements within the compound if. Replace with the above code to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why you are using !=true when your .equals method already returns a boolean. Try this.

```
String direction = s.readLine();
    System.out.println(direction);
    if ( direction!=null && !direction.equals("up") && !direction.equals("down")&& !direction.equals("left")&& direction.equals("right")){
        System.out.println("Invalid Solution file");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The quals method returns a boolean so the result does not need to be compared with the true or false value. Also, I would start with null comparison - boolean expressions in Java are shortened so if this part will be fulfilled rest of the expression is not evaluated. The correct expression might look like this:

```
if (direction == null || (!direction.equals("up") && !direction.equals("down") && !direction.equals("left") && !direction.equals ("right "))) {
}
```

But this code is not readable. You could use enums or list of Strings like below

```
    List<String> directions = Arrays.asList("up", "down", "left", "right");
    String direction = "readValue"
    if (!directions.contains(direction)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid direction");
        System.exit(0)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
boolean match = false;

if (direction.equals("up"))
{ match = true; }
if (direction.equals("down"))
{ match = true; }
if (direction.equals("left"))
{ match = true; }
if (direction.equals("right"))
{ match = true; }
if (direction.equals(null))
{ match = true; }
if (match == false){
    System.out.println("Invalid Solution file");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

You might also want to trim the direction string after reading from file.